# Display image on pug

Tags: image, express, pug

I'm new to NodeJS world.

I tried to display image from mongodb using pug and node express.

Please see my code and guide me.

**customer.pug**

```
extend layouts
block content
    h1.container #{title} of #{customer.full_name}
    div.container
        p Full Name: #{customer.full_name}
        p Address: #{customer.address}
        p Age: #{customer.age}
        img.imageScr1(src=customer.profileimage, alt=customer.full_name)
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer');

// set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads/',)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// init upload
const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage
});

// Middlewares
// middleware for Assets - to set public for assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));

// route - homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Customer.find({}, null, function(err, customers) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            // customers.profileimage = '/' + customers.profileimage;
            // console.log('image prefix::: ' + customer.profileimage);
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Customer List',
                customers: customers
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post('/customer/add', upload.single('profileimage'), function (req, res) {
    var customer = new Customer();
    customer.full_name = req.body.full_name;
    customer.address = req.body.address;
    customer.age = req.body.age;
    customer.profileimage = req.file.path;
    customer.save(function (err) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

I got following error when render customer.pug view.
[error_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnuPx.png)

I found that, if I add '\' before image path 'uploads\profileimage1520473825415.jpg', it displays image.

I tried many ways to do that did not work.

Please help me.

Cheers

Comment: solution is: img.imageScr1(src='/'+customer.profileimage)

Comment: Are you certain that your variable you are sending through to your pug template has a correct URL value? your syntax looks ok, check your compiled HTML and see what is showing

Comment: Hi @jayf93, thank you for your comment. the complied HTML showed src="/uploads\profileimage1521156405513.jpg", that is totally wrong. After that I used two black-slash as follows: img.imageScr1(src='\\'+customer.profileimage); it shows following compiled HTML: src="\uploads\profileimage1521156405513.jpg" which is valid url. Thanks a lot for that. :)